# Find sendmail version (sSMTP or Postfix or other)

Tags: linux, bash, sendmail

I have a script which runs on multiple servers. Some servers are using **sSMTP** and some are using **postfix**.

I want to find which version of **sendmail** my server is running in runtime, because `-t` is not supported in **sSMTP** but is mandatory in **Postfix**

Now the challenge begins.

`sendmail -V` on sSMTP variant outputs `sSMTP 2.64 (Not sendmail at all)`
but
the postfix variant doesn't have the `-V` option for displaying the version.

I managed to accomplish it with the following snippet.

```
VER=$(sendmail -V 2>/dev/null)
if [[ "sSMTP" == $VER* ]]; then
        echo $BODY | sendmail $EMAIL #sSMTP
else
        echo $BODY | sendmail -t $EMAIL #postfix
fi
```

Is there a more efficient method to achieve this?

I want to find what variant of sendmail is in my server. Not just postfix or sSMTP.

Comment: Can't you ask the package manager, e.g., `apt list`, what is installed?

Comment: Why do you think `ssmtp` doesn't support `sendmail -t`?  Mine does.  See the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp)

Comment: sendmail instance if ssmtp? @tripleee I don't think so!

Comment: I don't really understand your comment.  The man page I linked to shows that `ssmtp` does indeed ship a `/usr/lib/sendmail` which accepts the `-t` option with its (de facto) standard semantics.  Or are you talking about a different `ssmtp` than the one available in Debian under this name?

Comment: And [`-t` is optional with Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/mailq.1.html) just like with every other MTA which supplies a [`sendmail`](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html) compatibility wrapper. This optional option *(sic)* specifies that the recipient is specified in the headers of the message on standard input, so that you don't need to supply an (otherwise mandatory) explicit recipient address on the command line.

Comment: Oh I see! @tripleee Thanks 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
type -p sendmail |
xargs dpkg -S
```

[Some packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sendmail&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) put it in `/usr/lib`, others in `/usr/sbin`, etc.  This obviously requires them to be on your `PATH`.

`dpkg -S` tells you the name of the package which installed a file, and `type -p` is used to find `sendmail` on your `PATH` so we can pass that to `dpkg -S`.  This obviously requires a Debian-based distro (Ubuntu, Mint, what have you).

On an `ssmpt` system, with `/usr/lib` on the `PATH`, the output is

```
ssmtp: /usr/lib/sendmail
```

On a Postfix system with a slightly different `PATH`,

```
postfix: /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

I don't think I have an Exim or Qmail system where I can try this, but they should be predictably similar.

As an aside, if you want to pass a multi-line string such as an email message to `sendmail` by way of a pipe from `echo`, you will need to quote the multi-line variable in order for it to work.

```
echo "$body" | sendmail -t
```

If you want to use `sendmail -t`, the `"$body"` should contain the `To:` header for `sendmail` to parse -- this is what the `-t` option does, so I don't think you want a variable with a recipient address in this scenario.

Also, don't use uppercase for your private variable names; [uppercase variable names are reserved for system use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Finally, as already commented elsewhere, I believe both SSMTP and Postfix support `sendmail -t`, as does practically every other Sendmail implementation I have seen.  So in the end, I don't think you actually need this code to achieve that goal.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want ! Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Debian with sSMTP installed, with `/usr/lib` on path. `type -p sendmail|xargs dpkg -S` gives me `ssmtp: /usr/sbin/sendmail`.

Comment: Yeah, ssmtp installs it in both locations, so whichever is first on your `PATH` will get picked up. If that's what your comment is about?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more efficient method to achieve this?

Yes; don't try to find the sendmail version, and use a standard way of sending mail...

You should use the `mail` (or `mailx`) command for better compatibility

```
MAILCMD=$(type -p mail || type -p mailx)
echo "$BODY" | "$MAILCMD" "$EMAIL"
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but if the intent is to use `sendmail -t` where available, I don't think `mail` or `mailx` exposes that (and you sort of just move the target of the problem here; what if neither of those is available?)

Comment: @tripleee he only needed to use `sendmail -t` because according to his statement, it was mandatory on some postfix versions. I edited my post to reflect the reason of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that. I sort of agree that using a user-level utility is a reasonable fix for that, but `mail` and its derivatives is even less portable than `sendmail` because there are so many diverse implementations with different features. Of course, if you can assume Debian, like I do in my answer, you don't have that uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Postfix:

```
$ /usr/sbin/sendmail -C sdfsf
sendmail: fatal: open sdfsf/main.cf: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
75
```

sSMTP:

```
$ /usr/sbin/sendmail -C sdfsf
sendmail: No recipients supplied - mail will not be sent
$ echo $?
0
```

In your script you execute `/usr/sbin/sendmail -C sdfsf >/dev/null 2>&1` and test the return value, which is different depending on the MTA.

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -C sdfsf >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then   # return code 75 would mean Postfix
    echo sSMTP
else 
    echo Postfix
fi
sSMTP
```

In Postfix `-C` identifies the config file and if non-existent causes the `sendmail` to fail with an return code (75). sSMTP if run with or without the `-C` switch exits with a zero and message `sendmail: No recipients supplied - mail will not be sent`. Test the return value (`$?`) for identification.

Comment: My question is not just about ssmp or postfix! It's about all the kinda instances.. Even the original send mail.. How to do that!?

Comment: It is not unfathomable that you could diagnose each individual SMTP server by probing its failure modes, but that's going to be a lot of work, and if all you really care about is whether or not it supports the `-t` option, maybe just probe for that.  Like I remarked elsewhere already, it is portable to every `sendmail` I have tried, including `ssmtp` and (IIRC) `qmail`.